# CLEditor image align

Tags: jquery, cleditor

Is there a simple way to add

```
align="left"
```

into img tag for every inserted image?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS?

```
img { float: left; }
```

Comment: I cant use css as you offered, I just want to add align to image when any image added into editor screen. It's simple faq edit page. I just want faq content images as aligned left automatically in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "every inserted image", are you dynamically adding images into the page with jQuery?

If the answer is "yes" (dynamic images), for every image add a CSS class to the image:

`<img src="img/path.png" class="insertedImage" />`

And then define a CSS class in your CSS file:

`img.insertedImage { float: left; }`

If the answer is "no", then just add CSS that left-aligns every image on the page:

`img { float: left; }`

Comment: I cant use css as you offered, I just want to add align to image when any image added into editor screen. It's simple faq edit page. I just want faq content images as aligned left automatically in the editor.

Comment: What "editor"? Is this a rich text editor?  I still don't see why CSS does not work for you, as you have not provided enough of a context to your question in order to facilitate more specific answers.